# Value of type HTMLElement is not callable

Tags: jquery, typescript

I'm having a bit of a problem converting one of my JavaScript lines into TypeScript.

This line is used to create widgets of type `widgetName` on the container with id `containerId`. `widgetName` is a string:

```js
$('#' + containerId)[widgetName](options)
```

Example:
create an accordion widget without options on the div with id *example*

```js
$('#example')["accordion"]();
// which could be rewritten as:
$('#example').accordion();
```

Although valid JavaScript, TypeScript throws an error at the first line:

> Value of type HTMLElement is not callable

Can anyone help me with how I should write this statement? I can't cast `HTMLElement` to i.e. `JQueryStatic`. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can see this error happening if `widgetName` is an integer; `[widgetName]` will be retrieving the `HTMLElement` at that position in the jQuery collection, and the `(options)` would throw the error... but this wouldn't be valid JavaScript, let alone TypeScript.

Comment: @Matt `widgetName` is typed as a string and the result of `$(..)[string]` is an `HTMLElement`, which is causing the problem :)

Comment: ... then how can this ever work? You *can't* execute a `HTMLElement`, if you want to *create* one, you must use `document.createElement`...?

Comment: Well the problem is TypeScript assumes it's an `HTMLElement`. In fact i'm calling `$().accordion(options)` for example. Updated my question to make this clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the most recent version of the jquery definition file from definitely typed (https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts)?

It looks like this should work fine in your case (Lines 726/727) -

```
[x: string]: any;
[x: number]: HTMLElement;
```

Older versions of the d.ts had this incorrectly defined:

```
[x: string]: HTMLElement; // *WRONG*
[x: number]: HTMLElement;
```

(Update: Upon testing, I discovered I had the same error. Updating to the d.ts listed above fixes it).

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of upgrading it, but we're currently still on jQuery 1.7.1 and I was afraid there would be breaking changes? I'm going to try this out right away!

Comment: I don't know about that. You can fix the issue yourself easily enough though. Not sure what the line number is in your d.ts but just search for `[x: string]: HTMLElement;` on the JQuery interface and amend it to `[x: string]: any;` - I don't think that can break anything else.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution:

```
(<any>$('#example'))["accordion"]();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already using the jQuery UI's definition file and I need to keep the current syntax as it offers flexibility.

Comment: @Anzeo I thought you were getting the error on the other line :) I tend to write "the above line gives an error" or "the following line gives an error" to help quicker understanding.

Comment: Ah yes, I edited my question which is why it's unclear. I've updated it for future reference :)